# Change Font Color of Search Value Based on JSON Key

Tags: javascript, json, search, fonts, colors

I was doing a javascript exercise and wanted to add extra functionality onto it for practice. What I want to do is change the font color of the gem("Page" value in JSON file)  depending on a certain value in the json file.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4b3dad3b33.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Messing With Gems (JSON)</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="containter mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <h3 class="text-center mb-3">
                <i class="fas fa-gem"> Gem Look Up</i>
            </h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" 
                placeholder="Type gem/skill name..." />
                <div id="match-list"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');

// Search gems.json and filter it
const searchGems = async searchText =>  {
    const res = await fetch('../data/gemz.json');
    const gems = await res.json();

// Get Matches to current text input
let matches = gems.filter(gem => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
    return gem.Page.match(regex);
});


if(searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
}
outputHtml(matches);

};

//Show Results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
    if(matches.length > 0) {
      const html = matches.map(match => `
      <div class="card card-body mb-1">
      <h4>${match.Page}</h4> <em>(${match.gemdiscription})</em> <span class="text-primary">
      ${match.gemtags}</span>
      </div>
      `).join('');
matchList.innerHTML = html;
    }       


};

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchGems(search.value));
```

JSON Example ( For example if the "primaryattribute" key has the value of "intelligence" I want the key "Page" value to be displayed in blue on the website when you search for a gem ) I would like to do this with pure javascript to better understand how this is done.

```
    {
        "Page": "Frostbite",
        "gemdiscription": "Curses all targets in an area, 
making them less resistant to cold damage and giving them a chance to be frozen by cold damage.",
        "gemtags": [
            "Spell",
            "AoE",
            "Duration",
            "Curse",
            "Cold"
        ],
        "primaryattribute": "intelligence",

    }
```

Comment: Here is a live version of the search http://exilebuilder.rf.gd/

Comment: Why don't you fetch that json first? I wouldn't fetch on every input Event, if you don't have to. Use a condition and set an HTML class.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this in general this is just how they did it in the exercise. I am open to learning better methods to do things though if you would like to elaborate or give me and example of what you mean that would be awesome :) I was really just trying to mess around with the project and learn how to manipulate the json using javascript a bit.

Comment: I tried something like

 if(matches.primaryattribute === 'strength') {
        matches.Page.style.color = 'red';
    } `

Comment: `matches` is an Array. If you are using `.innerHTML`, which I don't recommend, then you will need get the Element you want using standard JavaScript methods after it is appended to the DOM. Let's say you ment `match.pramaryattribute` and `match.Page `... still `match.Page` would have to be a DOM Element to have a style attribute. Since fetch is a JSON file, it's not, as that would be invalid JSON.

Comment: What would your recommended way of doing this? If not .innerHTML because i'd be great to learn the correct method of doing this.

Comment: Use something like: `function M(tag){ return document.createElement(tag); } function resOut(page, descr, tags){ const d = M('div'), h = M('h4'), m = M('em'), s = M('span'); d.className = 'card card-body mb-1'; h.textContent = page;  e.textContent = description; s.textContent = tags.join(', '); d.appendChild(h); d.appendChild(e); d.appendChild(s); d.onclick = function(){ /*before adding to DOM*/ } return d; }`. That `function resOut`, with arguments passed correctly, returns a `div`. Use like: `matchList.appendChild(resOut('yourPage', 'yourDescription', ['a', 'b']));`. You can put in a loop.

Comment: In `resOut` you could add a `switch` or something to test against the page, like `switch(page){ case 'Frostbite': h.className = 'frost'; break; case 'AnotherGem': h.className = 'another'; break; }`. Set your style in external CSS before this.